# Is there any ETH wallet without transaction fees?

Tags: wallets, fees, jaxx

I have 2 questions to ask here:
First is there any ETH wallet that doesnt charge transaction fees?
Second, currently I using Jaxx wallet, I have 1 ETH in my account. If i want to send 1 ETH out, is it possible? Or do I need to purchase more ETH to cover the transaction fees?

Thank you.

Comment: Fees are part of ethereum not of you wallet. So no wallet without fees can exist except if someone pays the fees for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible **NOT** to have any transaction fees. Like centralized apps (paypal, etc.) you need transaction fees to cover for maintenance for their servers. With Ethereum and other blockchain and decentralized application you need these fees to give out to those "miners" who compute the next blockchain (think of it as a tip). But compared to centralized apps the fees for ETH differs you can either lower it or to make it higher to make your transaction faster.

As for your second question. I think you need to purchase more ETH coins just to cover for the transaction fee.

Answer (score 1):

Logically it is not possible since you have to pay `gas` fee in order to deploy your transaction. Basically each transaction has a base cost of 21,000 Gas, for the transfer of funds. In your wallet, it is always safe to keep your %1 of your fund always ready to cover up transaction fees.

The questions could be who will cover the cost. There are some exchanges ([for example](https://pro.btcturk.com/en/help/fees)) that does not charge you any transaction fees to transfer your funds such as for Ethereum, Bitcoin.